# How to remove headers revealing system info when sending mail in php

Tags: php, linux, security, email, ubuntu

I am using PHPs mail() function. I've noticed when going through the message (that gets sent) properties that some headers are present which specify

- the filename which sent the email
- which version of php I'm running
- my OS info

I've removed the domain, but this is basically what's included. How can I stop this being included, or am I just being security paranoid? Also, I would like to keep using phps mail function as opposed to setting up something else. Thanks.

```
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:emailtest.php
From: hidden@hidden.hh
Reply-To: hidden@hidden.hh
X-Mailer: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10
Message-Id: <20140315193810.ADD43120489@hidden.hh>
```

Comment: You could configure the local MTA to remove these headers.

Comment: At least the first of them is caused by [`mail.add_x_header`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.add-x-header), I don't know about the second `X-Mailer` one, that may be in `sendmail_path` perhaps.

Answer (score 16):

Thanks @Wrikken for pointing me in the right direction

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160205171448/http://thegeekoftheworld.com/how-to-remove-x-php-originating-script) highlights two properties in php.ini that can be changed:

```
mail.add_x_header = Off
expose_php = Off
```

I have no idea why they'd be on by default..

Comment: That seems to get rid of X-PHP-Originating-Script, but X-Mailer is still there.

Comment: Have you just copied the sample code from the PHP online manual? Because that includes a line to generate X-Mailer. Simply remove it, and it will disappear.

Comment: No, using the mail function alone.

Comment: mail.add_x_header = Off increased my SpamAssassin score 2 points!

Comment: Link is broken. Archive.org equivalent: https://web.archive.org/web/20160205171448/http://thegeekoftheworld.com/how-to-remove-x-php-originating-script

Answer (score 1):

For ultimate obscuration for all emails sent, you can control the postfix headers on the email server.  This also allows you to hide your obscure your hostname.  Major wrote a good article that should get you pointed in the right direction.  It's a little more advanced, but I think it's the way to go:

https://major.io/2013/04/14/remove-sensitive-information-from-email-headers-with-postfix/

Answer (score 0):

Apart from settings described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22429181/1183296)
this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/184) suggest removing X-Mailer header like this

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->XMailer = ' ';
```